# Inbox by Gmail signature not quoted

Tags: inbox-by-gmail, email-signature

I'm using Inbox by Gmail for my personal email, but when I add a default signature it is always showed as quoted text.

Can I avoid quoted text?

Comment: By 'quoted text', do you mean it shows beneath the message you are replying to, and you want it to show directly beneath your own message instead?

Comment: It is shown beneath my message and it is correct. I dont' want to change this. But my signature is shown in the e-mail like the text of the replying e-mail, so it is hidden. This is what i want to avoid.

Comment: Oh, right. This is default behaviour, and you can't change it as far as I know. Google automatically collapses content that is repeated - signatures, replies, anything else that is repeated - for ease of reading.

Comment: Ok thanks, so there is no solution. I hope that in future Google will give the choice for signature behavior.

Comment: It's not signature behaviour - it applies to any repeated text in any e-mail (whether sent by you or someone else).

Comment: Btw, I just posted a question about getting the signature to show directly underneath your message - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92864/58455 - since you've done this I would love your reply there!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the signature feature in Google Inbox (which by default, always added at the bottom of the message) - you can create a mail template with your signature, and use it only when you desire, when composing new message:

[image]

https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/7107959