# Display signature above quoted reply in Inbox by Gmail

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail, email-signature

It was easy to do in Gmail (select the checkbox marked *Insert this signature before quoted text in replies and remove the "--" line that precedes it*), but I might be missing something obvious in Inbox.

**How can you configure Inbox to add your signature *above* the quoted reply text, rather than below it?**

Comment: You can workaround it with an email template, see here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/112723/58166

Comment: Thanks @NoamManos, that’s not a bad idea. Not automatic of course, but better than the default!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this so far is using the [Mixmax addon](https://mixmax.com/). It'd be ideal not to have to install an addon, particularly because of the extra bloat it adds, but it seems easy enough with this addon to ignore everything else ;)

It specifically supports Inbox (as well as vanilla Gmail), and has the exact signature option I was looking for:

[image]

It seems to be quite nicely designed and coded as well, which is a plus.

One major downside: it adds this footer to the bottom of every e-mail you send:

[image]

It seems you can remove it on a per-email basis by clicking the **x**, but removing it automatically for every e-mail requires upgrading to a paid plan.

The footer doesn't bother me much particularly because it's underneath my signature and wouldn't be noticed by many, but I understand why it would bother some.

*I'll update this answer if I come across any better ways of placing the signature above the quoted text in Inbox.*